# Child action - blocked by ActionLink but not by custom helper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, async-await

Consider I have small helper for executing async action in child actions:

```
protected virtual TResult GetFromSynchornizedContext<TResult>(Func<Task<TResult>> taskFactory)
{
    return Task.Run(async () => await taskFactory()).Result;
}
```

Now I have some code in my child action:

```
public ActionResult SomeChild()
{
    this.ViewBag,Sth = GetFromSynchornizedContext(() => SomeAsyncThatRetunrsInt());
    return this.View();
]
```

In `SomeChild.cshtml`

```
<a href="@Url.Action("SomeAction", "SomeController", new { routeValue = ViewBag,Sth )" >Link</a>
```

causes:

> HttpServerUtility.Execute blocked while waiting for an asynchronous
>   operation to complete.

But, when I write own `Html.ActionLink` that bases on `Url.Action`:

```
public static IHtmlString ActionLink(
    this HtmlHelper helper,
    string actionName,
    string controllerName,
    object routeValues)
{
    UrlHelper urlHelper = new UrlHelper(helper.ViewContext.RequestContext);
    return  urlHelper.Action(actionName, controllerName, routeValues);
}
```

**error doesn't occur!**. I believe `@Url.Action` also calls `Action` from `UrlHelper` class. Why it happens?

Comment: Are you sure that the issue doesn't have to do with your `ViewBag` property not executing until you try to use it in your `routeValue`?  Are you invoking your custom `ActionLink` method in exactly the same way?

Comment: I am able to preview values of ViewBag while debugging so it is not a problem. Both links are called exactly the same.